# How to build a JPA converter for enumerations storing a key

Tags: java, jpa, enums, converters

I have enumerations with keys like:

```
public enum Unit {
Kilogram ( "KG" ),
Liter ( "L" );
String key = null;
Unit ( String key ) { this.key = key; }
public String getKey() { return key; }
public Unit findByKey( String key ) {
 for ( Unit unit : Unit.values()) {
  if ( key.equals( unit.key )) { return unit; }
 }
 return null;
}
```

I have quite a bunch of these enumerations, so I want to create one Converter like:

```
@Converter
public class EnumKeyConverter4jpa<E>
implements AttributeConverter<Enum, String> {
@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Enum arg0) {
    if ( arg0 == null ) return null;
    return arg0.getKey();
}
@Override
public Enum convertToEntityAttribute(String arg0) {
    if ( arg0 == null ) return null;
    return Enum.findByKey( arg0 );
}
}
```

Of course I always end up with "getKey()" and "findByKey()" are not known to "Enum". So maybe an interface helps, but I have no clue how to create this?

Comment: You cannot not do this simply because you do not know the `class` of the `enum` to convert the `String` into. You could use various methods, but they would not be type safe. You can create a base class that is generic in the `enum` type, you can then extend that base class for each of your `enum`s.

Comment: That sounds interesting. How do I create such a generic enum class and extend it? To my knowledge, enum is final.